# How to fix "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.mongodb.MongoClientOptions"

Tags: java, mongodb, tomcat

I am trying to migrate a REST API (Java-made, using Maven, in Eclipse) from own server to a partner's server. They have installed Tomcat 9 and Mongo 3.6.17 for us there (I have little control over it, but if really needed I can see for a installing newer/other versions). I have had many incompatibility problems, but can't find a fix for the following.

When calling any endpoint on the remote server, I get the following error (you can see I'm using Jersey):

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.mongodb.MongoClientOptions
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:489)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

I understand from what I read online that there is an incompatibility problem with the mongo Java driver. I have done many changes to the Mongo driver version, based on the compatibility tables I've found, but no luck. Currently it is set to:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

in my project's pom.

For reference, we use Tomcat 9 and Mongo v4.0.9 - but even with changing the driver version in our build, the services still run smoothly (e.g. when using v3.6.2 above), both on our server (Linux, don't know specs, I can update tomorrow) and when I run the service through eclipse on my local machine (Windows). The remote server runs on CentOS 7.6.1810 and has OpenJDK v1.8.0_242 installed. Conversely, we have the Oracle JDK 8 (slightly different versions on local machine and server - locally, I run 1.8.0_91).

Any ideas?

Comment: To create an instance of com.mongodb.MongoClientOptions you must assign the return of com.mongodb.mongoClientOptions.builder().  Not sure what your code is doing to instantiate the com.mongodb.MongoClientOptions object.

Comment: BTW - using MongoClientOptions means you are using the old client stack (which is implimented in the driver for backwards compatibility).  This client stack does not support sessions or transactions or change streams.  The new client stack uses com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings instead and supports the newer 3.6, and 4.0 features.  You may need to use the newer driver 3.12.1 to get these features too.

Comment: I don't instantiate com.mongodb.MongoClientOptions diretly, it is done internally when instantiating a MongoClient, like so: `MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient(Config.DB_URI);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't resolve it based on the java driver versions. Instead, I asked for Mongo to be updated (4.0.9) and it worked.